# How to use condition in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, case, select-case

I'm trying to use a select case in order to either use a where condition or not in a sql query. But it does not work and I can use some help how to solve this if possible

```
DECLARE @CategoryID Int
SET @CategoryID = 0
SELECT * FROM SomeTable 
CASE WHEN @CategoryID = 0 THEN 
ELSE
WHERE        (dbo.SomeTable.ID = @CategoryID)
END
```

So if I pass 0 to the `@CategoryID` parameter I should not filter at all, otherwise I want to filter. Can this be done?

Comment: The [references docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) show how to use the case expression.

Comment: @DaleBurrell The OP should not even be using `CASE` here.

Comment: You Can Use Dynamic Query. http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-dynamic-sql/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rephrase your logic to remove the `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE @CategoryID IN (0, ID);
```

This works, because when `@CategoryID = 0`, the `WHERE` clause is always true, otherwise it would be true when `ID = @CategoryID`.

Your current attempt is a common problem, stemming from not using a `CASE` expression as it is intended.  The *predicate* of a `CASE` expression (i.e. what follows the logic after `THEN` and `ELSE`) has to be a *literal* value, not another logical expression.  In this case, we don't even need `CASE`.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong... You have to rearrange your `where` clause:

```
DECLARE @CategoryID Int = 0;

SELECT * FROM SomeTable 
WHERE @CategoryID = 0 OR @CategoryID = ID
```

If variable is set to 0, then `where` clause is always true, otherwise, its value depends on condition `@CategoryID = ID`

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, first is to build your query based on your `case` condition

```
DECLARE @CategoryID INT
SET @CategoryID = 0
declare @strsql varchar(max)

set @strsql =  
    CASE WHEN coalesce(@CategoryID, 0) = 0 THEN 'SELECT * FROM SomeTable'
    ELSE
        'SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE 1 = '+ cast(@CategoryID as varchar(10)) + ''
    END
print  @strsql
exec sp_executesql @strsql
```